# Modifying text within a file using sed or awk

Tags: text, sed, awk, editing

I am trying to modify files to print part of the second column with it's corresponding sequence on the line below it. I've tried awk, sed and grep but I only get part of the text.

```
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_(null) range=chr1:20802866-20802871 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATAAG
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_(null) range=chr1:23866529-23866534 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TTATCT
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_(null) range=chr1:24345525-24345530 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GATAAG
```

To

```
chr1 20802866 20802871  GATAAG
chr1 23866529 23866534  TTATCT
chr1 24345525 24345530  GATAAG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'[=: -]' '/^>/{s=$3" "$4" "$5; next} {print s,$0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 'N; s/.*range=\([[:alnum:]]*\):\([[:digit:]]*\)-\([[:digit:]]*\).*\n\([[:alpha:]]*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4/' test.fa
chr1 20802866 20802871 GATAAG
chr1 23866529 23866534 TTATCT
chr1 24345525 24345530 GATAAG
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
awk -F "[=: -]" '{getline a; print $3,$4,$5,a}' file
```

Comment: The above is not a safe or appropriate use of getline. Don't use getline until you've read and fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: @Ed Morton, Can you explain why my example is incorrect? Thank you.

Comment: I wrote that article so I and others wouldn't have to keep explaining it. Once you understand that article you will not use getline like that any more. getline is a useful tool but awks primary function is to read every line in the file and apply condition/action rules to each so using getline to circumvent that behavior is a bit like carrying a bicycle.

Comment: @Ed Morton, You're right. I will be using getline only as a last resort.

Comment: the key is just to use it when appropriate. That article shows a pretty complete list of when it's appropriate to use getline and when used in those cases it's an invaluable tool.